# Anyone know how to repaint another image? C# windows mobile device to samsung omnia

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

```
private void pictBoxUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Up";
    pictBoxUp.Image=System.Drawing.Bitmap(
        "how do i select path for another image in my desktop");
}
```

these are the codes i'm testing around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys i solved it . When you connect to device, the path will be diff already. Answer : picturebox.Image = new BitMap(@"example.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.  Changing the image in the PictureBox is simple:

```
var pathToMyFile = "\\My Program\\myimage.png";

if(pictureBox.Image != null)
  pictureBox.Image.Dispose();

pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(pathToMyFile);
```

Your note does, however, say something about a "desktop".  If you're wondering how to load the image on the device when the image resides on a PC, well that's not so simple.  You need to find a mechanism (WCF service is probably the easiest) for the device to ask the PC for the picture.  The code for that is more complex than a simple SO answer.

Comment: guys i solved it . When you connect to device, the path will be diff already. Answer :

picturebox.Image = new BitMap(@"example.jpg");